# No test coverage in sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a multimodule maven project. I have 2 tests in it. Tests run during build and sonarqube shows that 100% tests (2) passed. But coverage is empty. Why is it? My other simple maven project uploads coverage successfully in sonarqube. I made the test in the same way in both projects.

Comment: Please provide more details, your configuration, sonarqube version. How do you have your coverage computed?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more ways to do it, but the best way I found is to use the Jacoco maven plugin, configure it to add it's agent to the Surefire execution (and, optionally, if you use integration tests, Failsafe) and then add these files to the SonarQube config.

A good explanation for this I've found [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/). The basic stuff is quite simply (here only for surefire):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
    <executions>
        <!--
            Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
            is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
        -->
        <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                <!--
                    Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                    for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                -->
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!--
            Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after
            unit tests have been run.
        -->
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
        <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
        <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests> 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With that you can configure your SonarQube (Settings -> Java) to find the jacoco unittest file at `/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec`, which should be enough to get the coverage reliably when running the `sonar:sonar` goal afterwards.